# Checking the convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent and for every $n$ the random variable $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[-\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n}]$. Denote $\sigma_n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \textbf{Var} X_k$. Identify the weak limit of the sequence
$$
Y_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{\sigma_n}
$$
So my attempts were to use Lindeberg's central limit theorem. Obviously we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \textbf{Var} X_k \equiv 1 \rightarrow 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{E} X_k \equiv 0 \rightarrow 0$, so we would expect $Y_n \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ (the standard normal distribution), but I have a problem with checking the Lindeberg condition which appears to be in a very ugly form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\mathbb E[X_k^2]=k\mathbb E[U^2]$, where $U$ is uniform on $[-1,1]$. Therefore, $\sigma_n^2$ is of order $Cn^2$ for some constant $C$.

In order to check Lindeberg's condition, we have to handle quantities like 
$$x_{n,k}:=\mathbb E\left[kU^2\chi\{|U|>\varepsilon nk^{-1/2}\}\right]$$
for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$. If $\varepsilon nk^{-1/2}\gt 1$, then $x_{n,k}=0$.

Comment: Ah, now I see, where I made the calculation error. Now everything's really simple, thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, one can show that the Lapunov's condition holds and therefore Lindeberg's condition too.